# How to properly deserialize encoded transaction?

Tags: web3.js, transaction, deserialization, serialization, sign

```
// Sign the transaction
  const feePayer = USER_KEYPAIR;

  const deserializedTx = Transaction.from(Buffer.from(swapTransaction, 'base64'));
  deserializedTx.partialSign(feePayer);

  const txnSignature = await SOLANA_CONNECTION.sendRawTransaction(deserializedTx.serialize());

  console.log("Transaction Signature:", txnSignature);
```

```
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
```

```
Error: Versioned messages must be deserialized with VersionedMessage.deserialize()
```

**Question: How to deserialize encoded transaction?**

P.S. It works with other encoded transactions, but not with my.
Example of the correct one:

```
AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAEDA+Z8BRyNDL30G+lsh0lwSNNhbnN6HAnoyUtyAiN7Pg+OUK2wQtYmX3uHnIO2htEANdTK9dP12UzWjFk+hpR4qAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAiOec80h+J5X8oUoZEmnxVj+E8V+0O4Nr9ly+Fu2D+8cBAgIAAQwCAAAAAOH1BQAAAAA=
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with calling `VersionedTransaction.deserialize`? The error message seems to lead you towards doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error, you are sending decoding a versioned message, ie, The version generally signifies the specifics of the layout of the message or instructions in it, if put in normal terms. And it tells you to use the `VersionedMessage.decode()`, but I don't think there is a function for it, as it is automatically handled, so my guess would be that there is some issue with the message serialization, or due to some dependency version incompatibility.